# Error:Element must be user-editable in order to clear it in robot framework when tried to enter value in %0 and notes section

Tags: robotframework

Please help me with the error am trying hard but not getting solution, even tried to click element before input

'Progress field' is having value as %0 already in the system , on mouse over it goes to element and by double click it becomes editable

Xpath Progress of the underline code
        xpath='//*[@id="myGrid"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]'

```html
<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="83" col-id="progress" class="ag-cell ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-no-focus ag-cell-not-inline-editing" style="width: 114px; left: 590px;  ">0%</div>
```

Script:

```
     ${Progress}=    get_Progress
     Sleep  2s
     Set Selenium Implicit Wait    25
     Mouse Over    xpath=${Progress}       
     Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    1 minute    30     get_Progress
     Set Selenium Implicit Wait    20
     Sleep   5s  
     Double Click Element    xpath=${Progress}  
     Click Element    xpath=${Progress}        
     Set Selenium Implicit Wait    25
     Clear Element Text   ${Progress}
     Input Text    ${Progress}      '${EMPTY}'
```

It's throwing error:

> InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

You must find the correct `input` element. The `div` element can't be cleared nor edited.

Comment: Located element with div and then entered text with input solved an issue ,thanks